# Javafxpackager: how do you set the "base JDK"?

Tags: javafx-8

When I run javafxpackager, I get the following warning/info:

```
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
```

It's not clear from the docs for  [Deploying JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) how one would specify an alternative JDK. There isn't an option for it, that I can see (maybe I'm blind). Is it a system property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an [old Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7) which mentions this.  Don't know if it is still applicable or relevant to your case or not though:

> **Self-Contained Applications: Select Java Runtime to bundle**
>
> Packager tools in 7u6 assume current JDK (based on java.home property)
>   is the source for embedded runtime. This is useful simplification for
>   many scenarios but there are cases where ability to specify what to
>   embed explicitly is handy. For example IDE may be using fixed JDK to
>   build the project and this is not the version you want to bundle into
>   your application.
>
> To make it more flexible we now allow to specify location of base JDK
>   explicitly. It is optional and if you do not specify it then current
>   JDK will be used (i.e. this change is fully backward compatible).
>
> New 'basedir' attribute was added to  tag. Its value is
>   location of JDK to be used. It is ok to point to either JRE inside the
>   JDK or JDK top level folder. However, it must be JDK and not JRE as we
>   need other JDK tools for proper packaging and it must be recent
>   version of JDK that is bundled with JavaFX (i.e. Java 7 update 6 or
>   later).
>
> Here are examples ( is part of  task):
>
> ```
> <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>      
> <fx:platform basedir="c:\tools\jdk7"/>
> ```
>
> Hint: this feature enables you to use packaging tools from JDK 7
>   update 10 (and benefit from bug fixes and other features described
>   below) to create application package with bundled FCS version of JRE 7
>   update 6.

Comment: Oracle has reordered their blog pages. Unfortunately the link to the 'old Oracle blog' is not correct any more.

Comment: where to add these lines??

Answer (score 8):

When run with the parameter `-Bruntime`:

```
javapackager.exe -Bruntime="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_76\jre\" ...
```

you get the following info:

> Using base JDK at: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_76\jre

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone, I wanted to use javapackager to bundle the 32-bit Java 8 JRE.  I was running into issues because the JDK was the 64-bit Java 8 JDK.  I was able to solve my issue by setting JAVA_HOME to the 32-bit JRE.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved same problem:

NetBeans ID - Tools - NetBeans Platform Manager - "Sources" tab

button Add ZIP/Folder

(there were no sources set so I set it and "No base JDK. Package will use system JRE."
disappeared)