# How to deploy JavaFX application as a native installer without including JVM runtime?

Tags: maven, javafx, installation, exe, native

I'm using maven and the javafx-maven-plugin to package my JavaFX as a windows installer using InnoSetup 5 and it all works well. The issue that I have is that jre is included within the installer, rather than using the system jre. This makes the installer to large for my small application and since my target group has jre or jdk installed on their system it is also unnecessary. How do I tell the plugin to not include a JVM and to point to the system JVM?

Answer (score 0):

In this question - [Javafxpackager: how do you set the "base JDK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025309/javafxpackager-how-do-you-set-the-base-jdk) there are answer about the JRE configuration.

So, if you set `<fx:platform basedir=""/>` it will not include JRE into your package (see [this document for details](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7)).

Comment: This does not seem to work for javafx-maven-plugin. Setting the  bundleArgument `<runtime></runtime>` to "blank" does not include JRE but does not automatically use the system JRE either. And it causes a 'VM not found' on execution. Is this a javafx-maven-plugin bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Show your `pom` file please. It would be better.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... but here you'll find the snippet of the pom [link](http://snip.ml/runtime-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from javafx-maven-plugin GitHub issue: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/293#issuecomment-303016297

If you want to remove the JRE from the bundle, just add this to your plugin-configuration:

```
<bundleArguments>
    <runtime />
<bundleArguments>
```

The location of the JRE is included inside the generated `.cfg` file (`jfx/native/...../app`). If there is `runtime=` (empty), then the locally installed JRE will be used (you have to have `JRE_HOME` being set on Linux-systems).

The `runtime=` seems to be set to empty after adding the `bundleArguments`, not sure why it didn't work for Tony.